# Decorators having strange behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to learn how decorators works and how to use them, but I'm getting a strange behavior.
The idea is to create a wrapper method to calculate the execution time (I know, have other ways to do this) and wrap a method called "cadastra_usuario_no_banco", this method just get a sleep and returns true.

```
import time
def tempo_de_execucao(funcao_original):
  def envolucro(*args, **kargs):
    tempo_inicio = time.time()
    retorno = funcao_original(*args, **kargs)
    tempo_total = time.time() - tempo_inicio
    print(" -------- envolucro --------")
    print("A função retornou", retorno)
    print(int(tempo_total), "Segundos para a execução")
  
  return envolucro

@tempo_de_execucao
def cadastra_usuario_no_banco():
  print ("iniciando cadastro de usuário")
  time.sleep(1)
  print ("Cadastro de usuário efetuado com sucesso!")
  return True
```

But, when I try to run using the follow instructions

```
a = tempo_de_execucao(cadastra_usuario_no_banco)
print(a())
```

I am getting two times the print and returns from the wrapper.

```
iniciando cadastro de usuário            # Execution of the wrapped method
Cadastro de usuário efetuado com sucesso!
 -------- envolucro --------             # The decorated execution 
A função retornou True                   # the correct return of the wrapped method
1 Segundos para a execução               # the time of the execution
A função retornou None                   # the strange behavior, that is not supposed to be here
1 Segundos para a execução               # is not supposed to be here too
None                                     # the print of the wrapper method (this is correct)
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: You don't need to do `a = tempo_de_execucao(cadastra_usuario_no_banco)`. That's what the decorator `@tempo_de_execucao` is for. Just call `cadastra_usuario_no_banco()`.

Comment: You're also missing a `return retorno`.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood, I was doing that wrong. After remove "a = tempo_de_execucao(cadastra_usuario_no_banco)" and call "cadastra_usuario_no_banco()" it works just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the comments and from the [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```py
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

Is equivalent to

```py
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

Decorators are functions that takes another function as arguments and returns a new function.

So you are calling it twice when you put `@tempo_de_execucao` above  `cadastra_usuario_no_banco` and also called `tempo_de_execucao(cadastra_usuario_no_banco)`, which resulted in `tempo_de_execucao(tempo_de_execucao(cadastra_usuario_no_banco))`